# How do I tell which version of Xcode/which SDK built an xcarchive?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have `xcarchives` for the various releases of my product, but I haven't been keeping track of which version of Xcode I built them with and with which SDK. How can I check?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you build an executable with Xcode, it includes extra keys in the application's Info.plist (not the xcarchive's):

```
DTCompiler: com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0
DTPlatformBuild: 13C75
DTPlatformName: iphoneos
DTPlatformVersion: 9.2
DTSDKBuild: 13C75
DTSDKName: iphoneos9.2
DTXcode: 0720
DTXcodeBuild: 7C68
```

`DTXcode` and `DTXcodeBuild` describe which version of Xcode was used to build the executable (and thus the archive). `DTSDKName` and `DTSDKBuild` describe the SDK used for the executable itself. The other information may be valuable to you, too.